# Set screenOrientation to "portrait" in release build only

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-orientation

In `**AndroidManifest.xml**` I have an `**Activity**` in portrait mode:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".home.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

I found it useful to temporary remove `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` line during development in order to earlier catch bugs related to saving instance state.

Is it possible to set screen orientation to portrait in the *release* build only and for the *debug* build keep the default behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

It can be achieved by mentioning configuration for release in `build.gradle` file of app using `manifestPlaceholder` property as shown below. And remove it from manifest file. Also for debug build you can specify separately as well.

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
            manifestPlaceholders.screenOrientation = "portrait"
        }
        debug {...}
    }
}
```

To understand more on `manifestPlaceholders` and build favour kindly refer [here](https://azabost.com/android-manifest-placeholders/) and at [official site](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#build-types)

Answer (score 3):

You can override parts of your AndroidManifest in debug build. In `src/debug` create another AndroidManifest.xml, and tell the merge tool to replace the screenOrientation attribute for your activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".home.MainActivity"
        tools:replace="android:screenOrientation"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified"/>
```

See [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge.html) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your activity,

```
if (!BuildConfig.DEBUG) setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```